# PHP - Zend Framework send file

Tags: php, zend-framework

I am trying to send a file to the browser in a Zend Framework PHP application. I found an action helper here - https://github.com/noginn/noginn/blob/master/Noginn/Controller/Action/Helper/SendFile.php

In my controller I have an action like this

```
public function downloadfileAction()
{
    //get the file name and strip out all white spaces
    $title = preg_replace('/\s+/', '', $this->getRequest()->getParam('title')); 

    //create the file path          
    $path = 'downloads/'.$title.'.pdf';

    //call the action helper to send the file to the browser
    $this->_helper->SendFile->sendFile($path, 'application/x-pdf');
}
```

my file is located in my public folder ie MyApp/public/downloads/myFile.pdf

When I run the action, I get a view file not found error and the download is not started.

```
exception 'Zend_View_Exception' with message 'script 'myController/downloadfile.phtml' not found ...
```

Can anyone suggest what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's an error about the script-(view)-file what can't be found. Cause you don't need one when sending output.

Try disable it by this this:

```
public function downloadfileAction()
{
    //get the file name and strip out all white spaces
    $title = preg_replace('/\s+/', '', $this->getRequest()->getParam('title')); 

    //create the file path          
    $path = 'downloads/'.$title.'.pdf';

    //call the action helper to send the file to the browser
    $this->_helper->SendFile->sendFile($path, 'application/x-pdf');
    $this->_helper->viewRenderer->setNoRender();
}
```